# Do folding cross country skis exist?

Tags: equipment, skiing

Do folding (or telescoping) cross-country skis exist and if so are they useable?

Comment: I SAW IN POPULAR MECHANIC ? navy seals winter skis that back part that enter the front part to make it shorter to travel when not needed navy seals have the info about those ski how ro reach them for more info ?

Comment: Cool, do you know which edition of popular mechanics it was in (month, year)?

Answer (score 3):

There is a folding ski system designed for snowboarders you can see [here](http://mtnapproach.com/index.html). 
I couldn't find any other cross-country folding ski available commercially.

Folding ski for cross-country is also patented under [US Patent 6616170](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/6616170.html).

Comment: The problem with the MTNApproach is that they're only for going uphill as far as I can tell (seems like the skins are permanent), meaning not cross-country capable.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Refineo's links, I was also able to find some other websites, but nothing really conclusive, or useful.

Similar to the MTNapproach skis: http://www.climb.co.at/index.php?lang=en

Russian Patent holder of folding x-country skis:
http://www.vector-ski.com/collski_e.html

Backcountry style, but no longer available for sale: http://www.zigzagtour.de/index2.htm

Home-made folding skis: http://www.woodly.de/blog/?p=41